# If every non-zero prime ideal of $R[t]$ is maximal then $R[t]$ is $PID$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Suppose $R$ is an integral domain such that every non-zero prime ideal of $R[t]$ is maximal. Show that every ideal in $R[t]$ is principal.

Please someone give some hints to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can proceed like this:

1. Because $R$ is an integral domain, the ideal $I = (t) \subseteq R[t]$ is prime (recall that an ideal is prime iff its corresponding quotient ring is an integral domain).
2. Since $I$ is prime, it is maximal by assumption.
3. Conclude that $R$ is actually a field.
4. Note that polynomial rings in one variable over a field are principal ideal domains.